# Axios request intercepted by interceptor not falling in catch block from initial request if error is Promise.rejected in interceptor

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, try-catch

I'm trying to handle some request errors using axios interceptors to better provide messages to the catch block which displays a toast in my application. But no matter what article, tutorial, video, or documentation I see they use `return Promise.reject(error)` to return the error in the interceptor. That does not work in my case, I'm working on react native project, so I thought it could be a problem of framework, but I managed to reproduce it on Code Sandbox.

**CodeSandbox Working Example:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-antonelli-s4iih0?file=/src/services/api.ts:85-86

**This is the Axios interceptors documentation** https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors

[image: Interceptors documentation screenshot]

And here is my interceptor:

```js
import axios from "axios";

import { AppError } from "../utils";

function errorHandler(requestError: unknown) {
  if (axios.isAxiosError(requestError)) {
    console.log("gets to the interceptor");
    if (requestError.response && requestError.response.data) {
      switch (requestError.response.status) {
        case 400:
          return Promise.reject(requestError);

        case 401: {
          return Promise.reject(new AppError("Failed to authenticate token."));
        }

        case 404:
          if (requestError.response.config.url?.includes("api")) {
            // return Promise.reject(new AppError('Email or password invalid'));
            throw new AppError("Email ou senha inválidos.");
          }

          return Promise.reject(requestError);

        default:
          return Promise.reject(requestError);
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(requestError);
  }
  return Promise.reject(requestError);
}

export const api = axios.create();

api.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (requestError) => {
    errorHandler(requestError);
  }
);
```

Here is my request function:

```js
  const handleSubmit2 = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("submit start 2");
      const data = await api.post("/api/not-movies-again", {
        email: "wow@email.com",
        password: "wow password"
      });
      console.log("REQUEST DATA 2: ", data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Catcher ERROR 2: ", error);
    } finally {
      console.log("submit end 2");
    }
  };
```

Not a single `return Promise.reject(error)` falls in the catch block. It turns out after hours hitting my head on this, I had the idea of throwing the error itself instead of rejecting it and it actually worked, the error fall in the catch block.

I could just be really dumb, but am I doing anything crazy wrong here? Am I hitting an edge case by simply handling my errors? Or is the documentation and every tutorial outdated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just forgot a `return` there:

```
api.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (requestError) => {
    // Here probably need to have a return
    return errorHandler(requestError);
  }
);
```

Comment: Bloody hell, I lost my mind on this yesterday, but I'm not even mad about it... typical silly mistake. Thanks a lot, mate.